# LinkedIn r_liteprofile doesn't give the public url and profile picture

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn made some changes in their V2 API for receiving User data.

I set my scope to `r_liteprofile` and use the `/v2/me` endpoint.

What I added is this: `me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)`.
This gets me the given basic profile details.

But what I also want is:

- LinkedIn public URL
- ProfilePhoto in URL

That can be done with `r_basicprofile`, but I cannot figure out how to apply for this "basis" profile information.

Any help?

Or can I fetch the Linkedin Public URL and Profile Photo based on the ID the `r_liteprofile` returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ProfilePhoto URL

This one is easy. Just use a `profilePicture.displayImage` argument in your projection as below. It will provide the full info about a picture:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))
```

The output looks similar to this - that's an output for my user:

```
{
   "profilePicture":{
      "displayImage":"urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg",
      "displayImage~":{
         "paging":{
            "count":10,
            "start":0,
            "links":[
               
            ]
         },
         "elements":[
            {
               "artifact":"urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100)",
               "authorizationMethod":"PUBLIC",
               "data":{
                  "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.mediaartifact.StillImage":{
                     "mediaType":"image/jpeg",
                     "rawCodecSpec":{
                        "name":"jpeg",
                        "type":"image"
                     },
                     "displaySize":{
                        "width":100.0,
                        "uom":"PX",
                        "height":100.0
                     },
                     "storageSize":{
                        "width":100,
                        "height":100
                     },
                     "storageAspectRatio":{
                        "widthAspect":1.0,
                        "heightAspect":1.0,
                        "formatted":"1.00:1.00"
                     },
                     "displayAspectRatio":{
                        "widthAspect":1.0,
                        "heightAspect":1.0,
                        "formatted":"1.00:1.00"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "identifiers":[
                  {
                     "identifier":"https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0/1612809737178?e=1622678400&v=beta&t=NCZOUXQokOyX5GN98uI2b4P90hg8h0QPgWQkq3qGLM",
                     "index":0,
                     "mediaType":"image/jpeg",
                     "file":"urn:li:digitalmediaFile:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100,0)",
                     "identifierType":"EXTERNAL_URL",
                     "identifierExpiresInSeconds":1622678400
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "artifact":"urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200)",
               "authorizationMethod":"PUBLIC",
               "data":{
                  "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.mediaartifact.StillImage":{
                     "mediaType":"image/jpeg",
                     "rawCodecSpec":{
                        "name":"jpeg",
                        "type":"image"
                     },
                     "displaySize":{
                        "width":200.0,
                        "uom":"PX",
                        "height":200.0
                     },
                     "storageSize":{
                        "width":200,
                        "height":200
                     },
                     "storageAspectRatio":{
                        "widthAspect":1.0,
                        "heightAspect":1.0,
                        "formatted":"1.00:1.00"
                     },
                     "displayAspectRatio":{
                        "widthAspect":1.0,
                        "heightAspect":1.0,
                        "formatted":"1.00:1.00"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "identifiers":[
                  {
                     "identifier":"https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1612809737178?e=1622678400&v=beta&t=EQsuIgcg7fE7eyjNbKdTQN5Iq29WogIii_B_ABusiDw",
                     "index":0,
                     "mediaType":"image/jpeg",
                     "file":"urn:li:digitalmediaFile:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200,0)",
                     "identifierType":"EXTERNAL_URL",
                     "identifierExpiresInSeconds":1622678400
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "artifact":"urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_400_400)",
               "authorizationMethod":"PUBLIC",
               "data":{
                  "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.mediaartifact.StillImage":{
                     "mediaType":"image/jpeg",
                     "rawCodecSpec":{
                        "name":"jpeg",
                        "type":"image"
                     },
                     "displaySize":{
                        "width":400.0,
                        "uom":"PX",
                        "height":400.0
                     },
                     "storageSize":{
                        "width":400,
                        "height":400
                     },
                     "storageAspectRatio":{
                        "widthAspect":1.0,
                        "heightAspect":1.0,
                        "formatted":"1.00:1.00"
                     },
                     "displayAspectRatio":{
                        "widthAspect":1.0,
                        "heightAspect":1.0,
                        "formatted":"1.00:1.00"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "identifiers":[
                  {
                     "identifier":"https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_400_400/0/1612809737178?e=1622678400&v=beta&t=9O2L6z2RprkxuHbcwvZk6Y9oy4tb0qerQ538BD6-VR4",
                     "index":0,
                     "mediaType":"image/jpeg",
                     "file":"urn:li:digitalmediaFile:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_400_400,0)",
                     "identifierType":"EXTERNAL_URL",
                     "identifierExpiresInSeconds":1622678400
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "artifact":"urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800)",
               "authorizationMethod":"PUBLIC",
               "data":{
                  "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.mediaartifact.StillImage":{
                     "mediaType":"image/jpeg",
                     "rawCodecSpec":{
                        "name":"jpeg",
                        "type":"image"
                     },
                     "displaySize":{
                        "width":800.0,
                        "uom":"PX",
                        "height":800.0
                     },
                     "storageSize":{
                        "width":800,
                        "height":800
                     },
                     "storageAspectRatio":{
                        "widthAspect":1.0,
                        "heightAspect":1.0,
                        "formatted":"1.00:1.00"
                     },
                     "displayAspectRatio":{
                        "widthAspect":1.0,
                        "heightAspect":1.0,
                        "formatted":"1.00:1.00"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "identifiers":[
                  {
                     "identifier":"https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1612809737178?e=1622678400&v=beta&t=4QtK4xiiTWkui0HtL1YDF22sXurosKWdXTUOzw0TxiY",
                     "index":0,
                     "mediaType":"image/jpeg",
                     "file":"urn:li:digitalmediaFile:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800,0)",
                     "identifierType":"EXTERNAL_URL",
                     "identifierExpiresInSeconds":1622678400
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Profile photo urls can be found next to each `identifier` element.

For example, here's one of the urls:

> `"identifier":"https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQELiWnd6svKQg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1612809737178?e=1622678400&v=beta&t=4QtK4xiiTWkui0HtL1YDF22sXurosKWdXTUOzw0TxiY"`

### LinkedIn Public URL

This is basically a `vanityName` attribute as written in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile):

> vanityName    The vanity name of the member. Vanity name is represented
> as a string is used for the public profile URL:
> [www.linkedin.com/in/{vanityName}](http://www.linkedin.com/in/%7BvanityName%7D).

However, as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context), only a limited number of information can be retrieved with `r_liteprofile`

> By default, only the Lite Profile Fields are returned for a profile request.

For a list of lite profile fields, please check this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/lite-profile). However, if you check it, you will find out that `vanityName` or the profile url is not included there. To have additional permissions, you have to request them as stated in the doc:

> To request more or less fields, you must have additional permissions
> that are only granted to select partners.

So, you have to be a **select partner** to get it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I rewarded you the bounty ;-) Any idea how I can become a selected partner? It's indeed the vanityName I need.

Comment: @user1469734 Thanks, you're welcome. I guess it's here https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply However, I've seen that not everyone qualifies for it. Still, you could give it a try.